# Calculate text width without rounding using Javascript

Tags: javascript, html, css

I have a div that I using Javascript to change the position of. However, it is rounding incorrectly.

```css
#hi{
  background-color: blue;
  width: 2px;
  height: 10px;
  position: absolute;
}
```

```html
<div id = "hi"></div>
<button onclick="myFunction()" style = "margin-top: 100px">Click me</button>

<script>
function myFunction() {
  
  var div = document.getElementById("hi");
  div.style.left = "0px";
  console.log("BEFORE: " + div.style.left);
  var moveBy = 109.8125;
  div.style.left = moveBy + 'px';
  
  console.log("MOVE BY: " + moveBy);
  console.log("NEW POSITION: " + div.style.left);
}
</script>
```

It should move it by 109.8125, but instead moves it by 109.813.

Any way to make it more accurate and move it to 109.8125?

It may seem like it is not that important, but I am doing this several times, so then it looks in the wrong place, relative to other elements.

Comment: Not sure what you're trying to do exactly in your project, but wouldn't using a `contenteditable` div help you?

Answer (score -1):

If you really need to prevent precision drift due to rounding error, I'd suggest you keep track of the value independently of the `style` attribute. Here's an example of how you could do it using a [data attribute](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Learn/HTML/Howto/Use_data_attributes):

```js
function myFunction() {

  var div = document.getElementById("hi");
  div.style.left = "0px";
  console.log("BEFORE: " + div.style.left);
  var moveBy = 109.8125;
  
  // track the current value as a data attribute,
  // which won't get rounded
  const left = div.dataset.left = parseFloat(div.dataset.left || 0) + moveBy;

  // apply the computed value as a style
  div.style.left = left + 'px';

  console.clear();
  console.log(`dataset.left: ${left}, style.left: ${div.style.left}`);
}
```

```css
#hi {
  background-color: blue;
  width: 2px;
  height: 10px;
  position: absolute;
}
```

```html
<div id="hi"></div>
<button onclick="myFunction()" style="margin-top: 100px">Click me</button>
```

Comment: That's the style value, which is subject to rounding. But subsequent clicks will compute it from the data value, which hasn't been rounded, which means the precision won't drift as the moves add up.